# Know intended RestController in Spring implementation of ResponseBodyAdvice

Tags: json, spring, logging

The Spring ResponseBodyAdvice allows for handling the JSON-Response. I want to write it to the logger but by this would also like to add the name of the RestController being invoked in this transaction.
Can anyone tell, whether the classname is somewhere available in the parameters of the instance of ResponseBodyAdvice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. The parameter "MethodParameter" supplied to the "beforeBodyWrite"-method contains the attribute "containingClass" which provides the name of the intended Controller (I found this with testing - did not find any docs about the use of this attribute until now). That will do for me